# MCAR missingness mechanism

Tags: r, missing-data

I would like to create a MCAR database in R from an existing complete one.
I would like to have only some variables with NA observations, here's the code I used:

```
data <-master
set.seed(685) 
prop.m = .15  
mcar   = runif(length(data[,1]), min=0, max=1)
diabetes.mcar = ifelse(mcar<prop.m, NA, data$diabetes)
hypertension.mcar = ifelse(mcar<prop.m, NA, data$hypertension)
antic_therapy.mcar = ifelse(mcar<prop.m, NA, data$antic_therapy)
years.mcar = ifelse(mcar<prop.m, NA, data$years)
data_mcar <- cbind(subset(data), diabetes.mcar, hypertension.mcar, antic_therapy.mcar, years.mcar)
```

Here's the problem: setting the seed I obtain the NA missing values for every variable just for the same observations:

> diabetes.mcar
>    [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0
>   [31]  0  0  0 NA  0 NA  1  0  0  0  1
>
> hypertension.mcar
>    [1]  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0 NA NA  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1 NA  0  0 NA  0  0  1  0
>   [31]  1  0  1 NA  1 NA  1  1  1  0  1
>
> antic_therapy.mcar
>    [1]  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0  1 NA  0  0  0  0
>   [31]  0  0  0 NA  0 NA  0  0  1  0  1
>
> years.mcar
>    [1] 69 77 70 75 68 73 68 66 71 51 75 NA NA 74 71 71 71 70 55 80 74 73 NA 78 73 NA 70 69 74 76
>   [31] 70 78 72 NA 77 NA 78 72 75 67 79

And this's not MCAR at all!

How can I fix it?
I have to define a different seed for every variable?

I've also tried in this way:

```
 mymatrix <- as.matrix(data)
 mcar   <- MCAR(db.complete = mymatrix, perc.miss = 0.15, setseed = 11)
```

but I obtain a s4 object and I don't know how to transform it in a data frame or export it as a csv.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simulation is MCAR in the sense that *rows* are missing completely at random. To have random observations within each column as missing you could use something like

```
data <- airquality  # data is maybe not the best name
m.prop <- 0.15
as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(i) { i[runif(length(i))<m.prop] <- NA ; i } ))
```

The idea is to run through each column (`lapply`), randomly assign missing using the same approach you used, and then combine them all back into a `data.frame`.

To update only some variable you can use the following approach

```
data <- airquality  # data is maybe not the best name
m.prop <- 0.15
cols <- c(1, 2) # Columns to select
data[,cols] <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[,cols], function(i) { i[runif(length(i))<m.prop] <- NA ; i } ))
```

Comment: This works just fine! I don't need to set a seed? If I would like to have only some variables in the database with NA and not all the variables, how should I do? Thank you!

Comment: You only need to set a seed if you want to ensure that you can reproduce your simulations. See updated solution if you only want to introduce `NA`s to only some of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, using the updated code I obtain just 2 (or whatever) columns in the new database, like the code `mcar.data1<-as.data.frame(lapply(data[1:4], function(i) { i[runif(length(i))<m.prop] <- NA ; i } ))`  if I want to keep all the columns of the old database and I want to introduce NA only in some variables I have to use this code for NA imputation of some columns and then add the other variables without NA?

Comment: Note the indexing on the LHS in the last line. You missed that

Comment: Oh yes!! Thank you!! This's so so cool!!! I didn't checked the database yesterday night!

Comment: Now I'm tried to check the mcar mechanism with the little test `LittleMCAR(data)` but I obtain this error `Error in mlest(x) : mlest cannot handle more than 50 variables.
In addition: Warning message:
In mysort(data) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range` How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Don't know. Asking the package maintainer would probably be a better bet.

Comment: Thank you! I will